# writing pom.xml for maven dependencies sharing same dependency

Tags: maven, dependency-management

I am creating my **custom-exception** dependency which uses **org.springframework.web** as its dependency.
so I will be using **custom-exception** as dependency in a **master-project** which also has **org.springframework.web** as one of its dependency.

so my concern is how do i write pom.xml file for **custom-exception** so that I can include it in **master-project** without getting any conflicts.

Any extra information regarding dependency versioning and scope will be appreciated.

> This is the first time I am creating maven dependency

Comment: What do you mean by `..without getting any conflicts.`? If you have a dependency and having `main-project`  where you are using your own project that means your `main-project` will get the dependencies of your `custom-project`?

Comment: yes... this might be silly question but i am a total beginner in creating maven dependency @khmarbaise

Comment: It's not a problem to be a beginner, but you should answer a question? What do you mean by `..without getting any conflicts.` how? Where Problems?

Comment: @khmarbaise actually i dont know whether it will give any conflict or not.

Comment: Ah Ok that's an answer too(great). You can check in your main project via `mvn dependency:tree` if the versions are ok or not. If they different you might need to upgrade the version in your `customer-project`... ?

Comment: @khmarbaise that what I was looking for. mvn dependency:tree

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217266/discussion-between-khmarbaise-and-hilal-kaldane).